# How to add query parameters to useFirestoreConnect

Tags: typescript, firebase, redux, redux-firestore

I am using `useFirestoreConnect` to get all the data in 'todos' from firebase.

```
useFirestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: 'todos',
    },
  ]);
const todos = useSelector((state: any) => state.firestore.data.todos)
```

I only want to get data which includes the uid of the user. The docs on `useFirestoreConnect` only show how to get data based on a doc id.

```
useFirestoreConnect([
  {
    collection: 'todos',
    doc: todoId
  }
])
const todo = useSelector(
  ({ firestore: { data } }) => data.todos && data.todos[todoId]
```

Based on examples I have seen here I have tried the following:

```
useFirestoreConnect([
  {
    collection: 'todos',
    where: ["owner", "==", auth.uid]
  },
]);
const todos = useSelector((state: any) => state.firestore.data.todos)
```

Results in:

> FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

```
useFirestoreConnect([
  {
    collection: 'todos',
    query: ["owner", "==", auth.uid]
  },
]);
const todos = useSelector((state: any) => state.firestore.data.todos)
```

Results in a type error:

> Type '{ collection: string; query: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to figure it out. `auth.uid` was undefined. I just passed in the correct auth id and it worked. This is the correct way of adding parameters.

```
useFirestoreConnect([
  {
    collection: 'todos',
    where: ["owner", "==", auth.uid]
  },
]);
const todos = useSelector((state: any) => state.firestore.data.todos)
```